# Routes not working with index.php in url Laravel 4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, routes, laravel-4

I have an application using Laravel 4. And I modfied the .htaccess file so I can redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com. Here is the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

When I go to a route like mydomain.com/account/create all works fine, but when I go to mydomain.com/index.php/account/create I get a file not found error. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Is your setup able to handle path info? Does going to `mydomain.com/index.php?/account/create` work?

Comment: This will redirect me to homepage.

Comment: Do you get a laravel 'file not found' error - or a server 'file not found' error?

Answer (score 2):

It is not working - because laravel is not designed to have index.php in your route.

I'm guessing you are coming from the old Codeigniter days when some sites still have index.php in their route - but this is a different routing system.

Just use the normal routes.

Comment: This is strange, because in my local environment was working. Altough I don't intend to use like this. I made a .htaccess fix for this.